# Automatic Issue Assignment in sonarQube 5.6.6 - Not working

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using sonarqube 5.6.6 and I've installed the sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3. The author of the committer is available in the source code. Can any one please describe the step in detail for auto assign the issue to the last committer.

Creating the project name as login credential and adding the SCM account name for the particular project.

[image]

Thanks,
Sangeetha k

Comment: You should have a look at https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure sonarqube can perform a mapping between the author of the commit and a user in the sonarqube DB. The field "login" and "email" are automatically taken into account and you can specify additional SCM Accounts.
You could also update the SVN Plugin, the current version is 1.4.0.522.

Comment: Thanks Marco. I have updated the SVN plugin to 1.4 but still automatic issues assign for the user is not working. All the issues are assigned to the group. I've created the login based on the project. for example, project xxx , I'll create the user and group as xxx and I'll add all the developer scm name in the "create user" page. while running the analysis all the issues are assigned to the group not the particular scm user available in the group. But the author of the issue and SCM name that I configured is same. can you please help me.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Can you please explain the step briefly. I can't able to resolve the issues.

Comment: Can you please guide me for the "automatic issues assignment", whether I need to use LDAP plugin?.I'm creating the credential based on the project. I would really appreciate any possible help to move forward.